# Tray to write data in excel by Form made with Python - error

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Im trying to make a form to write data in an `*-xlsx` file
and append data at the last row but I am stuck...
Any advice would be appreciated

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

sg.theme('DarkTeal7')

EXCEL_FILE = 'InsertFormInExcel.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please fill out the foloving fields:')],
    [sg.Text('Name', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(key='1')],
    [sg.Text('Last_Name', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(key='2')],
    [sg.Text('Favorite Colour', size=(15,1)), sg.Combo(['Green','Blu','Red'], key='3')],
    [sg.Text('I speak', size=(15,1)),
                         sg.Checkbox('German', key='4'),
                         sg.Checkbox('Spanish', key='5'),
                         sg.Checkbox('Hrvatski',key='6')],
    [sg.Text('Broj djece', size=(15, 1)), sg.Spin([i for i in range (0, 10)],
                                                  initial_value=0, key='7')], 
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Button('Clear'), sg.Exit()]
]

window = sg.Window('Simple data entry form',layout)

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key]('')
    return None

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Clear':
        clear_input()
    if event == 'Submit':
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE,  index=False)
        sg.popup('Data saved')
        clear_input()
window.close()
```

Little help would be great - thanks

Comment: Any help iz welcome!!!